# Check for first available/missing id in an list using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements with id's like this:

```
<li id="item_1">Item 1</li>
<li id="item_2">Item 2</li>
<li id="item_4">Item 4</li>
```

Now, if I want to add another element to the list, I want to find the first available/missing id by going in a numerical order. So in this case it would be `item_3`, which would then be inserted between `item_2` and `item_4`.

Something like this?

```
var myArray = [];

$('li').each(function(e) {
  var myID = e.id;
  myArray.push(myID.substring(myID.length -1));
});

//Find the first available/missing number using the array somehow?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function getNextId() {
    var nextId; 
    $('li').each(function(i,el) {
        var nameId = el.id.split("_")[1];
        if (i + 1 < nameId) {
            console.log("Found",i,nameId,el);
            nextId = i;
            // return false will break jquery each loop
            return false;
        }
    });
    // nextId is 0 based so 0 is first element
    return nextId+1;
}

console.log(getNextId());
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/YDwy3/

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1; true; i++){
    var item = $("#item_"+i);
    if(item==null){
        // insert html
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fuZu3/)</kbd>

```
var id = $('li[id^="item_"]').map(function () {
    return parseInt(this.id.replace('item_', ''));
}).get(); //get array of all id's li starting with item_
var max = id[id.length - 1]; //get maximum id number
for (var i = 1; i < max; i++) { //run loop from 1 to second last value 
    if (id.indexOf(i) === -1) { // if id  number not preset in li than 
        $('<li>', { // create li 
            html: 'Item ' + i, // with html like Item_Number
            id: 'item_' + i //create id item_Number
        }).insertBefore($('#item_' + (i + 1))); //insert it before next item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(
function (){
    var myArray = [];
    $('li').each(function(i, elm) {
      var myID = elm.id;
      idArr = myID.split("_");
      currId = Number(idArr[1]);
      if(typeof prvId != 'undefined'){
        if((prvId + 1) != currId){
           $('#item_'+prvId).after("<li id='item_"+(prvId+1)+"'> Item " +(prvId+1)+" </li>");
        }
      }
      prvId = currId;
    });

}
);
```

Above code works on

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 4
Item 5
Item 7
Item 9
Item 11
Item 12
.....
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/S4mRj/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  var p = $(".list");
  var result = 1;
  var pp = $("li[id^='item_']", p);
  for (var i = 0; i < pp.length; i++) {

    if (result == parseInt(pp[i].id.split('item_')[1])) {
      result++;
      continue;
    }
    else
      alert('found ==> ' + result);
  }
});
```